# Excel parse cell value

Tags: parsing, excel, vba

I have placed the following in cell A1:

`"a lot of text marker: xxx  some more text"`

I would like to copy the `xxx` value into cell `A2`.

Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Do you want to "replace" a fixed text (xxx) with nothing, do you want to know in which cell strings xxx is found? Is it based on "xxx" or anything after the word marker: ? please show a before and after.

Comment: I dont want to change the value of A1 just update the value of A2 with    my marker value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=MID(A1, FIND("marker:",A1) + LEN("marker:"), 4)
```

I am assuming that the xxx (per your example) is 3 characters long and a space is present between "marker:" and "xxx".

Comment: thanks, works great. One small typo, the ',' needs to be replaced with ';'

Comment: @thedev: Whether to use , or ; depends on which locale you are in. It seems, you have non-US (or European) version of Excel installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents. Find() is case sensitive so if the text in A1 is

"a lot of text Marker: xxx some more text"

Then Find will give you an error.

You can use Search() in lieu of FIND()

=MID(A1, SEARCH("marker: ",A1) + LEN("marker: "), 3)

Also depending upon your regional settings you might have to use ";" instead of ","

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a VBA solution, this worked for me using your sample input:

```vb
Function GetValue(rng As Excel.Range) As String
  Dim tempValue As String
  Dim arrValues() As String
  ' get value from source range
  tempValue = rng.value
  ' split by ":" character
  arrValues = Split(tempValue, ":")
  ' split by spaces and take the second array element
  ' because there is a space between ":" and "xxx"
  GetXXXValue = Trim$(Split(arrValues(1), " ")(1))
End Function
```

To use, put this code into the sheet module (see [Where do I paste the code that I want to use in my workbook](http://www.rondebruin.nl/code.htm#Sheet) for placement assistance) and then put the following into cell A2:

`=GetValue(A1)`